# I don't understand this synthesis and transformation question

Tags: creative-writing

"I'm writing a letter to Kelly now", Mary told her mother.

Mary told her mother that she was writing a letter to Kelly. Now I don't know what to replace the "now" with.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question clearly. Do you mean the difference between: 'Consequently, I'm writing a letter to Kelly.' and 'I'm writing a letter to Kelly at the moment.'???

Comment: Just boldfacing your entire question does not help anyone understand or answer it, so I rolled back that edit.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Please [edit] your question to elaborate what your exact question is. Why do you need to replace the "now"? You can make a paragraph by having one empty line (press Enter twice). There is a help bar at the top of where you are writing markdown that can help you. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm sorry, but your question is VERY confusing. It seems to me this is an exercise you have to do for school and are stuck. If that's the case, please make it explicit instead of leaving us wondering what to do with your question. Give us the exercise's prompt and explain what synthesis and transformation means in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I might rephrase that quote one of these ways:

> Mary told her mother she was in process of writing a letter to Kelly.
>
> Mary told her mother she was currently writing a letter to Kelly.
>
> Mary told her mother she was writing a letter to Kelly at the moment.

As noted in comments, "now" in the original could also be taken to mean "as a consequence (of factors not included)"; that would lead to phrasing like these:

> Mary told her mother that had prompted her to write a letter to Kelly.
>
> Mary told her mother she needed to write a letter to Kelly.
>
> Mary told her mother Kelly deserved a letter for this situation.